# React-bootstrap ToggleButtonGroup uses old value when calling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I have a form using ToggleButtonGroup from `react-bootstrap`. I need to change some text values in the form based on the value selected in the toggle. The problem is that when calling `onChange` on the button - I got the previously selected value of the toggle, not the new one.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.tradeInput = React.createRef();
}

handleChange() {
    console.log(this.tradeInput.current.props.value); // old value printed here
}

<ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="trade" defaultValue="BUY" ref={this.tradeInput} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}>
    <ToggleButton value="BUY">BUY</ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton value="SELL">SELL</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Could someone suggest how to fix this?

EDIT: Very strange thing is happening when I try to read the value in my reference:

`console.log(this.tradeInput.current)` shows the correct updated value in the `current.props.value` but if I try to print `console.log(this.tradeInput.current.props.value)` with the exact same input, it gives me different result (the old value).

EDIT2: Full updated code

```
class ResourceTradePanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            validated: false,
            caps: 0,
            junk: 0,
            food: 0,
            trade: "BUY"
        };

        this.handleJunkChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFoodChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTradeChange.bind(this);
        this.updateCaps.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
      ...
    }

    handleJunkChange(event) {
        this.setState({ 
            junk: event.target.value
        });
        this.updateCaps();
    }

    handleFoodChange(event) {
        this.setState({ 
            food: event.target.value
        });
        this.updateCaps();
    }

    handleTradeChange(event) {
        this.setState({ 
            trade: event.target
        });
        this.updateCaps();
    }

    updateCaps() {
        var capsInfo = 0;
        const junk = parseInt(this.state.junk);
        const food = parseInt(this.state.food);
        if (this.state.trade === "BUY") {
            capsInfo = (junk + food) * 2;
        } else if (this.state.trade === "SELL") {
            capsInfo = junk + food;
        };

        this.setState({ 
            caps: capsInfo
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <Card>
            <Card.Body>
                ...
                <Form 
                    id="resourceForm"
                    noValidate
                    validated={this.state.validated}
                    onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}
                >
                            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                                <FormControl
                                    name="junk"
                                    type="number"
                                    min={0}
                                    max={10}
                                    value={this.state.junk}
                                    onChange={e => this.handleJunkChange(e)}
                                />
                                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                    <Translate id="labels.resourceLimitExceeded" />
                                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                            </InputGroup>
                            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                                <FormControl
                                    name="food"
                                    ref={this.foodInput}
                                    type="number"
                                    min={0}
                                    max={10}
                                    value={this.state.food}
                                    onChange={e => this.handleFoodChange(e)}
                                />
                                <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                                    <Translate id="labels.resourceLimitExceeded" />
                                </Form.Control.Feedback>
                            </InputGroup>
                            <InputGroup>
                                <FormControl
                                    type="number"
                                    disabled
                                    value={this.state.caps}
                                />
                            </InputGroup>
                            <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="trade" defaultValue={this.state.trade} onChange={e => this.handleTradeChange(e)}>
                                <ToggleButton variant="outline-dark" value="BUY"><Translate id="labels.buy" /></ToggleButton>
                                <ToggleButton variant="outline-dark" value="SELL"><Translate id="labels.sell" /></ToggleButton>
                            </ToggleButtonGroup>
                </Form>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    }
};
```

Comment: can u try to get value from `e.target.value` ?

Comment: Theoretically, I can, but I prefer using refs since there are other inputs for which I track changes so I need this function to be universal.

Comment: Change `this.tradeInput.current.props.value` to `this.tradeInput.current.value`

Comment: @KOTIOS this gives  me `undefined`

Comment: it seems that you have not binded the onChange Handler properly try to bind it like `this.handleChange.bind(this)`  on onChange

Comment: @KOTIOS Thank you for the suggestion. I tried adding the binding but it does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i find the problem... try this

```
    handleTradeChange(event) {
     // trigger you updateCaps() after updated the current state.
        this.setState({ 
            trade: event.target
        },()=> this.updateCaps(););

    }
```

try this, you can access you togglebutton current value any where using this.state.tradeValue

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      tradeValue : "BUY" 
    } 
    this.tradeInput = React.createRef();
}

handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({ tradeValue : value})
}

<ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="trade" value={this.state.tradeValue}  onChange={this.handleChange}>
    <ToggleButton value="BUY">BUY</ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton value="SELL">SELL</ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Comment: This works only when I react to the change of the toggle button. It doesn't work if some other form input changes and I need to get the current value of my toggle.

Comment: store your value in state and you can access it anywhere... why do make more complex....

Comment: I get it. There is one last problem. My state seems to be one value behind the event's value. Seems like the event.target.value and state.whatever are not synchronized and the state is always one value behind.

Comment: update you code with what you tried. that will be better.

Comment: I posted the whole code with the exception of totally irrelevant parts.

Comment: you do not need e.target.. the handlechange param only have value... so use it directly. and add value prop to <ToggleButtonGroup value={this.state.trade}/ >

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192370/discussion-between-sathish-kumar-and-smajl).